# Selecting most and least brightened vertices in a model

Tags: python, lighting, geometry

Let's say there is a point light source which is casting light on a model. There will be some most and least brightened vertex/vertices on the model due to point light source. Is there a way to select only these vertices i.e vertices which are most and least brightened or somehow extract their (x,y,z) coordinates?

Comment: The "most and least lit vertex" are not trivial to find arbitrarily out of thin air, and can only be accurately found as the result of rendering or possibly even baking. From there you would have to do reverse lookup from a baked texture back to geometry

Comment: You could look into the BVHTree.FromObject().ray_cast() function. I was fiddling with it a bit yesterday, I couldn't really figure it out. But I think it's at least a step in a direction you might be looking for.